# Java - how to use a selector for udp?

Tags: java, select, udp

In another help thread, I was told to use a `select()` method for my UDP server, but I have no idea how to implement it. My program was hanging on a `socket.receive()` statement, and I was told using `select()` would help.

Thanks.

Comment: You were not told to use `select`, it was a blind suggestion. You need to post your code inline for others to look at before they can get to the root of your problem.

Comment: *sigh* can someone just tell me how to use it?

Comment: You stated in your [last post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262342/java-udp-applet-freezing) that your applet was just a two person endeavor. If this is the case, using a `Selector` over the typical thread-per-connection approach will most likely incur a performance penalty, but without seeing your code it will be difficult to know. My initial assumption on your issue is that you're blocking the Event Dispatch Thread, but again, I'd need to see your code to know.

Comment: I hosted my code in its entirety in that post. I'd be glad to comment it, if that helps.

Comment: Personally (and I'm sure many people will feel the same), I don't want to go through the trouble of unzipping your code and importing it to a project. You should either post the relevant portions of your code (IE, where it freezes) in your question, or create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of your problem, so we can simply copy and paste it into a project.

Answer (score -1):

If your code is hanging on a receive() method, that's what it is supposed to do. If you don't want it to block forever, call DatagramSocket.setSoTimeout() with a suitable value.

Asking how to use NIO on a forum is not appropriate. There are tutorials on the Oracle site, and sample code is provided in the JDK.